# Does .Net reuse the same thread over different requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, thread-safety

I have the following class:

```
public static class ThreadStaticContainer
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _valueDictionary;

    public static Dictionary<string, string> ValueDictionary
    {
        get { return _valueDictionary ?? (_valueDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()); }
    }
}
```

And it is called in my MVC Action like this:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    ThreadStaticContainer.ValueDictionary.Add("1","1");
    return View();
}
```

And every so often I get the exception:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

Which surprises me because I thought that each request got a new thread. But it's acting as if sometimes a request will reuse a thread.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads are expensive.

To avoid creating too many threads, ASP.Net handles requests on reusable threads from the ThreadPool.
Therefore, you cannot use `[ThreadStatic]` like that.

Instead, you should store things in `HttpContext.Items`.

Comment: So, each request will get a thread, but that thread might not be "new" and clean. The thread will come from the thread pool and may have been previously used by a request. Is that true?

Comment: @Ev.: Correct.  (except replace "may" with "usually")

Comment: I see. Thank you. And to paraphrase you one more time, you're suggesting that if I store my data in the HttpContext I'll get a more accurate 1-1 mapping between request and stuff-related-to-the-request, because it'll be destroyed at the end of the request. Correct?

Comment: @ev: Strictly speaking, you don't have a guarantee of whether it will be destroyed after the request or, if it's ever destroyed, _when_ it will be destroyed. You just know it won't be used again for a different request.

Comment: I get ya. Thanks mate. Final question, can you think of any other issues with using the [ThreadStatic] in this way?

Comment: @Ev.: What is "this way"?

Comment: @Ev.: isn't the one issue sufficient? Just don't use it for this purpose.

Comment: Can you see any problems in storing data in a thread static dictionary? If we don't have access to the HttpContext, and I make sure the data is set at the beginning of each usage (negating the issue with re-use). Can you see any issues with that?

Comment: @JohnSaunders, it's a valid issue that's for sure. I'm actually trying to come up with a solution to something a little bit more complex that in my example. I'm writing an aspect that can basically bind into an optional parameter at any point in an app. The problem is that the HttpContext isn't always there for me. But I know the end points so I can make sure thread static stuff is set.

Comment: @ev:`HttpContext.Current` is always available, just may sometimes be `null`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Sometimes I'll be consuming from a console app.

Comment: Yes, I validated this by having a static thread local with an incremental static int as value - the request index should increase for every new thread but instead it remained between 1 and 2 (for image streaming thread I guess) - meaning the threads were reused so the thread local was not clean on a new request